# HashMap .get() returns null for every value except the last one

Tags: java, string, null, hashmap

I have a file with different names like this:

```
Thomas Danny
Jack Thomas
Danny Mike
Thomas Kate
Victor James
```

Edit: I have single spaces between names so it splits correctly, this isn't the problem.

Each pair represents who invited who to the party
My task is to get to the bottom of the cycle via HashMap.
For example, when given "Kate" as an argument, the program needs to print out "Jack", because Thomas invited Kate and Jack invited Thomas.

My code so far:

```
 Map<String, String> whoInvited = new HashMap<>();
    String[] pairs = text.split("\n");
    for (String pair : pairs){
        String[] invite = pair.split(" ");
        whoInvited.put(invite[1], invite[0]);
    }

    System.out.println(whoInvited.size())
    //Returns 5
    System.out.println(whoInvited.get("Danny"));
    //Returns null
    System.out.println(whoInvited.get("James"));
    //The only one that returns anything besides null(returns "Victor")

    String lookingFor = "Kate";
    while (whoInvited.containsKey(lookingFor)){
        lookingFor = whoInvited.get(lookingFor);
    }
    System.out.println(lookingFor);
}
```

I don't understand how does the HashMap get messed up like this. If i use the .get() function inside the for-loop, it gives me the value perfectly, but right after the loop ends, it becomes messed up, only having the last value.

Printing out whoInvited gives me just "=Victor}"

EDIT: FIXED!

Comment: Time to use a debugger to see what in fact is going on as the code runs.

Comment: "gives me just "=Victor}"" this suggests that the input data isn't what you describe.

Comment: Add a `System.out.println(whoInvited);` to see the contents of `whoInvited`.

Comment: @M.leRutte last line of the question.

Comment: @AndyTurner     System.out.println(lookingFor);?

Comment: @M.leRutte the last line of the *question*, not the code: "Printing out whoInvited gives me just "=Victor}"".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: After loading the map, rather than look at individual entries, try printing the whole map `System.out.println(whoInvited);` and see if it looks correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is caused by the fact that line endings differ on different Operating Systems. Windows uses `\r\n` while Unix uses `\n`. When splitting on `\n`, some weird stuff happens because of the `\r`. Replacing `text.split("\n")` with `text.split("\r\n")` will fix the problem for Windows.

Comment: Split on `\R`, like this: `text.split("\\R")`, which means "newline" for any OS.

Comment: or `text.split(System.lineSeparator())`

Answer (score 1):

It is not putting nulls, you have space-separated content. When you split on a space, you get many empty values because you have multiple consecutive spaces:

```
"Thomas    Danny".split(" ")
==> String[5] { "Thomas", "", "", "", "Danny" }
```

This explains why `invite[1]` resolves to a blank string. And because **map keys are unique**, each blank key overwrites the preceding one, and you're left with just the last one.

You can get around the problem by just splitting on any number of consecutive spaces:

```
"Thomas    Danny".split(" +")
==> String[2] { "Thomas", "Danny" }
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, I just formatted it incorrectly at first. I edited it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting the lines on whitespace, but this will cause empty strings to be emitted between whitespaces within the string. For your example this means `invite[1]` will almost always be `""`.

This means the key will always be the same value, resulting in only the last value being retained.
To fix this you should split using a regex expression to handle multiple whitespaces like `\s+`, then the values in the split will be actual strings.

Comment: This isn't the problem, I just formatted it incorrectly at first. I edited it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one space between the names. You shoud better use regex for splitting. 
Try pair.split(" +")

Update:
Is your file format unix or windows ???
Try this for splitting new line:
String lines[] = string.split("\r?\n");

Comment: This isn't the problem, I just formatted it incorrectly at first. I edited it as it is.

Comment: EDIT:
Is your file format unix or windows ???
Try this for splitting new line:
String lines[] = string.split("\\r?\\n");